# Redux-Saga not able to correctly read response from fetch api

Tags: javascript, redux, es6-promise, saga, redux-saga

Hi How do I read the data coming back from a fetch call:

```
export function* fetchMessages(channel) {     
    yield put(requestMessages())
    const channel_name = channel.payload
    try {      
        const response = yield call(fetch,'/api/messages/'+channel_name)

        const res = response.json()
            console.log(res)
        yield put(receiveMessages(res,channel))


   } catch (error){      
       yield put(rejectMessages(error))
   }      
}
```

When i console.log(res) I get:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Array[7]
```

How do I get my "info" (side Array[7] from this promise? I am new to all this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**response.json() is async and returns promise**

change this

```
const res = response.json()
```

to

```
const res = yield response.json()
```

[webpackbin](http://www.webpackbin.com/4ky16G6c-) example